# iOS Tap Gesture in a UIScrollview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I have a `RootViewController` & it's associated `nib` or `xib` file. This `nib` is loaded as the app starts. This `nib` file contains a `UIScrollView` in this scrollview I put another custom generated `nib` - `newNib.xib` file.

In this `newNib.xib` I have made changes in interface builder to respond to `RootViewController` i.e. Custom Class - `RootViewController`. Then I linked some UIView objects that I created in `RootViewController`. All fine so far...

I have defined some `tapGestureRecognisers` in `RootViewController` on the `UIViews` defined in `newNib.xib` but they are not responding to the tap events. Tap Events i defined in `RootViewController` like this -

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *messagesTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(messagesBucketTap:)];
[messagesTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[messagesTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
[self.messagesSnippet addGestureRecognizer:messagesTap];
[messagesTap release];
```

here `self.messagesSnippet` is present in `newNib.xib` Also I load the `xib` in `RootViewController` like so -

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"newNib" owner:self options:nil];`

But still I dont get the tapGesture to the selector (messagesBucketTap). What am i doing wrong?

Comment: are you declaring the method that gets triggered -  (void)messagesBucketTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture ? and what is messagesSnippet exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you ***forgot to set the delegate of the tap gesture recognizer*** e.g. `[messagesTap setDelegate:self]`.

Assuming `-messagesBucketTap:` is declared in the same class, Change your code to:

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *messagesTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(messagesBucketTap:)];
    [messagesTap setDelegate:self];
    [messagesTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [messagesTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
    [self.messagesSnippet addGestureRecognizer:messagesTap];
    [messagesTap release];
```

If this doesn't work, check what Jamie said, and make sure you are declaring:

```
- (void)messagesBucketTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
```

and not

```
- (void)messagesBucketTap;
```

Also, are you tapping once with two fingers?  Lastly, ensure that that `userInteractionEnabled` is **YES** on the UIView's and that `exclusiveTouch` is **NO** on the `UIScrollView`